# Get Albumart in .mp3 file for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How can i get the AlbumArt image in the mp3 file?  I am developing Windows Store app with c#.

MusicProperties class gives me Album name artist name vs. But it cant give me albumart.

Comment: I think you need to use ID3 tag reader library because `file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();` doesn't give you album art.

Comment: I try to use taglib# but when I get the file and create taglib file , ı get an error. Access denied. There must be other way.

Comment: Can you post the code which you've tried ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out MSDN sample to show thumbnail of any file. It also consists how to retrieve the album art.

[File and folder thumbnail sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-and-folder-thumbnail-1d530e5d)

If you want to save the album art check out [How to store save Thumbnail image in device in windows 8 metro apps c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843315/how-to-store-save-thumbnail-image-in-device-in-windows-8-metro-apps-c-sharp/18844387#18844387)

**UPDATE 1**

`MediaFile` is `StorageFile`. `ImageControl` is `<Image ... />`

```
using (StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await MediaFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 300))
{
    if (thumbnail != null && thumbnail.Type == ThumbnailType.Image)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(thumbnail);
        ImageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. But how I can use the thumbnail in BitmapImage variable ?

Answer (score 3):

here's my quick and short solution for that problem thirding TagLib#: (http://taglib.github.io/)

```
using TagLib;
var file = TagLib.File.Create(filename);
var bin = (byte[])(file.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
imageBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here [How to: Get IDE Tags and Thumbnails of a file](http://ks-developer.com/tutorials/read_mp3tags.html)

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

//Get Album cover
using (StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 300))
{
     if (thumbnail != null && thumbnail.Type == ThumbnailType.Image)
     {
         bitmapImage.SetSource(thumbnail);
     }
     else
     {
         //Error Message here
     }
}
```